# What's an intuitive or visual solution to calculate the probability to draw at least $k$ red balls after $n$ tries with replacement?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

- There is a bowl with red and blue balls.
- The probability to draw a red ball is $p$.
- Afterwards, the ball will be replaced, so the probability to draw a red ball won't change.
- What's the probability to draw at least $k$ red balls after $n$ tries?

Comment: How far can you get with this?  Can you calculate the probability of drawing exactly $k red balls?

Comment: Look up "binomial distribution".

Comment: $\binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$ is the probability of *exactly* $k$ red balls after $n$ tries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question, immediately you notice ${k\leq n}$. It's an obvious fact, but worth stating (we are only picking one ball per try, so clearly the highest number of red balls we can get, $k$, is clearly less than or equal to the number of tries we perform, $n$).

We want to know the probability of getting **at least $k$** red balls. This means you must take into account getting ${k,k+1,...,n}$ balls, also. For example, if ${n=10}$ and ${k=5}$, then if I get $6$ red balls after ${10}$ tries, then that is indeed at least $5$, and so must be included as part of our calculation.

So what we could do, is calculate the probability of getting exactly $k$ red balls, then calculate the probability of getting exactly ${k+1}$, then getting ${k+2}$... then getting ${n}$. What do we do with these probabilities? Well, we sum them up. So

$${P\left(\text{getting at least $k$ red balls after $n$ tries}\right)=\sum_{i=k}^{n}P\left(\text{probability of getting exactly $i$ red balls}\right)}$$

$${=P(\text{getting exactly $k$ red balls}) + P(\text{getting exactly ${k+1}$ red balls}) + ... + P(\text{getting exactly $n$ red balls})}$$

Now the only thing left to calculate is the probability of getting exactly ${k}$ balls (if we have this formula, obviously you can replace $k$ with ${k+1,k+2...}$ whatever you want).

Well, if I got ${k}$ red balls consecutively, then in the rest of the tries got blue balls (that is, in the first $k$ tries, I get red balls each time, then in the last ${n-k}$ tries got blue balls each time) then clearly this probability will be

$${p^k(1-p)^{n-k}}$$

where ${p}$ is the proportion of red balls to total number of balls (or if you like, the probability of getting a red ball in a single try).

But this isn't the only way of getting $k$ red balls. For example, I could have done

$${p^{k-1}p^{n-k}p}$$

That is, get ${k-1}$ red balls, then ${n-k}$ blue balls, then another red ball to finish. This is what the factor of

$${{n\choose k}}$$

keeps track of for you. It's a factor that tells you how many ways this could have occurred.

Hence

$${P\left(\text{getting exactly $k$ red balls}\right)={n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}}$$

Now, we can simply plug this into our above sum. And we get

$${P\left(\text{getting at least $k$ red balls after $n$ tries}\right)=\sum_{i=k}^{n}P\left(\text{probability of getting exactly $i$ red balls}\right)}$$

$${=\sum_{i=k}^{n}{n\choose i}p^{i}(1-p)^{n-i}}$$

And you are done.

Answer (score 2):

You already have a nice mathematical discussion
of your questions in @Riemann's answer (+1).
My answer will be more computational and visual
for a particular special case.

Suppose $p=0.7$ and you will have $n=10$ draws from the bowl with replacement. The you have a binomial probability model $\mathsf{Binom}(n = 10, p = 0.7).$ Let $X$ be the number of red balls drawn. Then
$$P(X = k) = {10 \choose k}p^k(1=p)^{10-k} 
= {10 \choose k}(0.7)^k(0.3)^{10-k},$$
for $k = 0, 1, 2, \dots, 10.$

This function is programmed into R statistical software
so that we can find the probability $P(X=6) = 0.2001$ in R as follows:

```
dbinom(6, 10, .7)
[1] 0.2001209
```

Some probability books have tables in the back with
enough particular values listed to work most of the
problems in the book.

The binomial coefficient ${10 \choose 6} = \frac{10!}{6!\cdot 4!}$ counts the
210 ways in which you could get exactly 6 red balls among 10. A few of them are listed below:

```
RRRRRRNNNN  RRRRRNRNNN ... RRRNNNNRRR ... NNNNRRRRRR
```

Each of these has probability $(.7)^6(.3)^4.$ So altogether, $P(X = 6) = 210*(.7)^6(.3)^4 = 0.2001.$

```
choose(10, 6)
[1] 210
.7^6*.3^4
[1] 0.0009529569
210*.7^6*.3^4
[1] 0.2001209
dbinom(6, 10, .7)  # repeat from above
[1] 0.2001209
```

Now suppose you want $$P(X \le 5) = P(X = 0) + P(X = 1) + \cdots
+P(X = 5) = 0.1503.$$ By hand, that would require you to compute six probabilities using the formula displayed above, and add them together. In R, this kind
of 'cumulative probability' can be found with the
function `pbinom` as follows:

```
pbinom(5, 10, .7)
[1] 0.1502683
sum(dbinom(0:5, 10, .7))
[1] 0.1502683
```

The probability tables in some probability books are
cumulative tables.

If you want $P(X \ge 6) = 1 - P(X \le 5) = 0.8497,$ you can
get the answer in R as follows:

```
1 - pbinom(5, 10, .7)
[1] 0.8497317
sum(dbinom(6:10, 10, .7))
[1] 0.8497317
```

Here is a bar plot of the distribution $\mathsf{Binom}(10, 0.7).$ It doesn't have good enough resolution to get
exact probabilities, but I hope you can roughly use
bar heights (adding them as needed) to see that they
match the computations above.

```
x = 0:10;  PDF = dbinom(x, 10, .7)
plot(x, PDF, type="h", lwd=3, col="blue", 
     main = "PDF of BINOM(10, .7)")
abline(h=0, col="green2")
```

[image]

The average number of balls drawn is $E(X) = np = 10(.7) = 7.$ in this particular case, $P(X = 7)$ is the largest
probability in the distribution.